# pasar variable a un updateOrCreate para subir archivo Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, archivo, eloquent

Estoy intentando subir 2 documentos pdf a laravel y guardar el nombre del archivo en mi base de datos.

Los documentos si se guardan correctamente, pero en la base de datos no se guarda el nombre de los documentos.

la variable `$nombre_curriculum_pdf` y `$nombre_curriculum_pdf` son las que almacenan el nombre del archivo, pero al llamarla desde el `updateOrCreate` no recibe el nombre del documento.

pd: el formulario si tiene el multipart
`<form id="profesor-frm" name="profesor-frm" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('profesor.store') }}"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Este es el controlador

```
if ($request->hasFile('curriculum_pdf')) {
                $file_pdf = $request->file('curriculum_pdf');
                $nombre_curriculum_pdf = time().$file_pdf->getClientOriginalName();
                $file_pdf->move(public_path().'/pdf_files/', $nombre_curriculum_pdf);
            }
            if ($request->hasFile('contrato_pdf')) {
                $file_pdf = $request->file('contrato_pdf');
                $nombre_contrato_pdf = time().$file_pdf->getClientOriginalName();
                $file_pdf->move(public_path().'/pdf_files/', $nombre_contrato_pdf);
            }

            profesorModel::updateOrCreate(['id_profesor' => $request->id_profesor],
                [
                    'rut' => $request->rut,
                    'nombre' => $request->nombre,
                    'apellidos' => $request->apellidos,
                    'correo' => $request->correo,
                    'clave' => $request->clave,
                    'telefono' => $request->telefono,
                    'fecha_nacimiento' => $request->fecha_nacimiento,
                    'direccion' => $request->direccion,
                    'curriculum_pdf' => $nombre_curriculum_pdf,
                    'contrato_pdf' => $nombre_contrato_pdf
                ]

            );

            $message= array(
                'message' => 'Profesor ha sido agregado con exito',
                'type' => 'success'
            );

            return redirect()->back()->with($message);
```

Comment: tienes `curriculum_pdf`  y `contrato_pdf` en el array `$fillable` del modelo `profesorModel`?

Comment: Si, estan los 2

Comment: Ya esta solucionado, y efectivamente el problema estaba en mi modelo, no me habia dado cuenta que tenia un nombre diferente a la columna de la db, muchas gracias!

Comment: Ah, genial. No veía nada raro en el código de la pregunta.